# Javascript - Showing TypeError: player is null

Tags: javascript, typeerror

```js
var playPauseBtn = document.getElementById("play-pause");
var player = document.getElementById("header-video");
player.removeAttribute("controls"); // <--- error is here
playPauseBtn.onclick = function() {
  if (player.paused) {
    player.play();
    this.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  } else {
    player.pause();
    this.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="header-container" role="banner">
  <div class="top-image test-top"></div>
  <!-- top image at the bottom of header -->
  <div id="header-video-container" class="zoom">
    <img id="header-fallback" src="yourimage.jpg" alt="" />
    <!-- fallback image for header video -->
    <video id="header-video" controls loop muted playsinline width="1280" height="720" role="img">
                <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/nb-show-reel.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <!-- if adding track/subtitle see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/Multimedia -->
            </video>
  </div>

  <a id="play-pause" class="hover-anim" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <!-- video player control -->
</div>
```

Hey guys I'm using this script for video. But when we inspect things it showing TypeError. So can you guys help me to fix this? Thanks :)

Showing error in this line: `player.removeAttribute("controls");`

Comment: Where is your javascript injected? it sounds like it's executed **before** the DOM is ready. Either wrap the script **at the very end** of the body tag, either register your code after the DOM is ready: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', function(){ // your code here });` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 3):

possible reasons are:

1- you are not assigning this id "header-video" to any tag.
OR
2-this JS code ran before the html is actually rendered in browser DOM.

solution:

1- check if you have assigned the same id without spelling errors.
2- use your JS once the DOM is loaded completely.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // all of your js code.
});
```

Note: putting your script tag in end of body should also work.

Comment: I have used that id in html.

Comment: look for the second possible reason then. use this DOMContentLoaded event. :)